# Что такое bash?

Tags: bash, shell

Подскажите для понимания:

можно ли сказать, что Bash — это просто расширение функционала Shell, как в случае PowerShell к cmd?

Comment: 2 - думаю нет. bash вроде бы более старый чем windows. 1 - странный вопрос.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*unix shell* (оболочка операционной системы *unix*) — это стандарт, являющийся **частью** [набора стандартов *posix*](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/POSIX).

программа *bash* — это одна из множества **реализаций** стандарта *unix shell*.

---

да, как и практически любая из реализаций практически любого стандарта, программа *bash* «умеет» значительно больше, чем описано в стандарте *unix shell*, но называть программу «расширением стандарта», естественно, неправильно.

Answer (score 1):

Это два разных вопроса. Их стоило бы разделить.
По второму вопросу: bash - это не расширение над sh ( если я правильно понял, что Вы понимаете под Shell ). Это отдельная оболочка, в которой многие вещи обратно совместимы с sh, но некоторые - нет.

Answer (score 0):

Строго говоря и PowerShell -- не совсем расширение для cmd, сказанное выше об отношении bash к shell применимо и к PowerShell: это другая оболочка, обратно совместимая с cmd.

Answer (score 0):

Ныне `/bin/sh` это алиас на что-нибудь в системе, но изначально `bash` это расширение обычного sh (  усовершенствованная и модернизированная вариация командной оболочки Bourne shell (sh).[читаем тут](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bash) . Если скрипт с башизмами - то использовать нужно `/bin/bash`, если POSIX-совместим - то `/bin/sh`.

Ссылки [раз](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Major-Differences-From-The-Bourne-Shell), [два](https://books.google.nl/books?id=dEJDrFfET7QC&pg=PA736&lpg=PA736&dq=bash%20vs%20sh&source=web&ots=SNYvg_zzsn&sig=7dbL1FMWLG0SsxgB4i5eK7GHzRA&hl=en#PPA736,M1)